# How to store files attached to MMS from Twilio phone number into laravel database?

Tags: laravel, twilio

I am working on developing a website using Laravel 7. I also have a Twilio phone number that receives multimedia messages with attached files, and I want to store these files within my website's database. and I want to know what is wrong in the process

My controller Code is

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\MMSMedia;
use App\Services\MediaMessageService\IMediaMessageService;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Magyarjeti\MimeTypes\MimeTypeConverter;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\Twiml;


class MessagingController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Messaging Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller receives messages from Twilio and makes the media available
    | via the /images url.
    */


    protected $twilio;
    protected $accountSid;
    protected $twilioNumber;
    protected $twilioNumberSid;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->accountSid = env('TWILIO_SID');
        $this->twilioNumber = env('TWILIO_NUMBER');
        $this->twilioNumberSid = env('TWILIO_NUMBER_SID');
        $authToken = env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');

        $this->twilio = new Client($this->accountSid, $authToken);
    }


    public function handleIncomingSMS(Request $request, IMediaMessageService $mediaService)
    {
        $converter = new MimeTypeConverter;
        $NumMedia = (int)$request->input('NumMedia');
        $FromNumber = $request->input('From');
        $MessageSid = $request->input('MessageSid');

        for ($i=0; $i < $NumMedia; $i++) {
            $mediaUrl = $request->input("MediaUrl$i");
            $MIMEType = $request->input("MediaContentType$i");
            $fileExtension = $converter->toExtension($MIMEType);
            $mediaSid = basename($mediaUrl);

            $media = $mediaService->getMediaContent($mediaUrl);

            $filename = "$mediaSid.$fileExtension";

            $mediaData = compact('mediaSid', 'MessageSid', 'mediaUrl', 'media', 'filename', 'MIMEType');
            $mmsMedia = new MMSMedia($mediaData);
            $mmsMedia->save();
        }


        $response = new Twiml();
        $messageBody = $NumMedia == 0 ? 'Send us an image!' : "Thanks for the $NumMedia images.";
        $message = $response->message([
            'from' => $request->input('To'),
            'to' => $FromNumber
        ]);
        $message->body($messageBody);

        return (string)$response;
    }


    public function deleteMediaFromTwilio($mediaItem)
    {
        return $this->twilio->api->accounts($this->accountSid)
            ->messages($mediaItem['MessageSid'])
            ->media($mediaItem['mediaSid'])
            ->delete();
    }

    public function allMedia()
    {
        $mediaItems = MMSMedia::all();
        return $mediaItems;
    }


    public function getMediaFile($filename, Response $response)
    {
        $media = MMSMedia::where('filename', $filename)->firstOrFail();
        $fileContents = $media['media'];
        $MessageSid = $media['MessageSid'];
        $mediaSid = $media['mediaSid'];
        $MIMEType = $media['MIMEType'];

        $media->delete();
        $this->deleteMediaFromTwilio(compact('mediaSid', 'MessageSid'));

        return response($fileContents, 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', $MIMEType);
    }

    public function config()
    {
        return ['twilioNumber' => $this->twilioNumber];
    }
}
```

and my table in database is

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMMSMediaTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('m_m_s_media', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('mediaSid')->index();
            $table->string('MessageSid')->index();
            $table->string('mediaUrl')->index();
            $table->binary('media');
            $table->string('filename')->index();
            $table->string('MIMEType');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('m_m_s_media');
    }
}
```

I did what the process need but i do not know why it is not working

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is not working? Do you get an error message? Have you tried debugging the webhook to see what happens? Are the media files being downloaded by your `mediaService`?

Comment: I meant that the files did not store in my database

Comment: So the files were downloaded? And was there an error thrown at all?